# How do I query a CSV dataset that's been imported?

Tags: questdb

I have imported data from CSV into Questdb using the web console but I can't query any values from it. I can see it in the list of tables but if I run something like this:

```sql
select * from imported-data.csv;
```

I get an error saying:

```
function, literal or constant is expected
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the table hasn't been renamed, you have to escape the filename with singlequotes, i.e.:

```sql
select * from 'imported-data.csv';
```

And if you want to rename the table to something else, you can also easily do this [with RENAME](https://questdb.io/docs/reference/sql/rename/):

```
RENAME TABLE 'imported-data.csv' TO 'newTable';
```